# How do I reload the clock applet?

Tags: gnome-panel, applet, clock

It seems I am running [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/580735). Sometimes my clock applet just stops running, and I have a pop-up window saying 'The clock has quit unexpectedly'. Between 'Reload' and 'Close', I have unfortunately chosen the second option. Even if I have rebooted, I cannot launch the applet anymore. I am on Ubuntu 10.10.

Can somebody give me the command line that I could use in the application launcher appearing when <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> are hit ? Or any other solution in order to recover the applet on the gnome-panel ?

Comment: **ATTENTION**: For users running **unity**, see my answer above, at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you didn't tell the panel to "delete" the clock applet, you should be able to get it back with a simple restart of the gnome-panel itself.  Just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, then run :

```
killall gnome-panel
```

That will restart the panel and reload your clock.

If you've deleted the clock applet, you'll have to re-apply it.  Right click on an empty area of your panel, right click and choose "Add to panel".  Then find and choose the "Clock" applet, then hit the add button at the bottom.

Comment: +1: If it's not there after a reboot, it most likely has been removed.

Answer (score 20):

If `killall gnome-panel` **didn't work for you**, that's because you're using a newer version of Ubuntu, running Unity. The command then should be

```
killall unity-panel-service
```